# How to enable RNDIS host mode in Android

Tags: kernel, android-13

I am building Android 13 AOSP but I need to enable RNDIS host mode from kernel. I am not sure which config flags need to be added to the kernel in order to enable RNDIS host mode. Can anybody help?